# css confusing media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using this snippet of code:

```css
 @media only screen 
    and (min-width: 1280px)
    and (max-width: 1365px) 
    and (min-height: 768px) 
    and (max-height: 800px) {
    #titleContainer{
        width:100%;
        min-height:94.55px;
        max-height:94.55px;
        background-color:#333333;
        display:flex;
    }
}
```

But when I see it in Google developer tools in 1280x800, what is displayed is the following:

```css
 @media only screen
    and (min-width: 1366px)
    and (max-width: 2047px)
    and (min-height : 1024px)
    and (orientation:landscape) {
    #titleContainer{
        width:440px;
        min-height:94.55px;
        max-height:94.55px;
        background-color:#333333;
        display:flex;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this in an external stylesheet?  If yes, can this be a cache problem?  In Chrome developer tools, Network tab, you can click the checkbox "Disable cache" and then refresh to make sure.

Comment: yes, it is in an external stylesheet, i did what did you said, but i can't see any difference

Comment: OK. Do you have a URL?  Something is strange because if you have a height of 800px, a media query with a min-height of 1024px; should not be used.

Comment: No, i haven't..is there, another way to see this?

Comment: That will make it harder, but a few questions may be able to help debug.  1) Does the second block of code appear anywhere in your css file?  2) If not, what other external stylesheets (if any) do you have?  Check through them and figure out which one this line appears in.  3) If you still have not found it, type Ctrl+U in Chrome for your website and search in the source code.  4) Don't forget that the code could be minified.  Once you have found where it is, post back with the location.